# How can I write this differential equation system in MATLAB?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I am newbie MATLAB user. How to write this equation system in MATLAB?

$$\frac{dN_{ik}}{dt}=\sum_{j=i}^{n}\sum_{l=1}^{n}\beta_{jl}b_{ikjl}S_{jl}N_{jl} - S_{ik}N_{ik}$$

Here, I want to know if I take $n=3$ or any constant number what kind of equation system will I have?

How can i run this loop without entering $\beta$, $b$ and $S$ functions. I just want to see matrix form of this system. Sorry for my bad English,  thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

The function for the right-hand side and arbitrary parameters should look something like this:

```
function dNdt = rhs(t,N,par)

dNdt = zeros(length(N),1);
nk = length(N)/par.n;

for i = 1 : par.n
    for k = 1 : nk
        for j = i : par.n
            for l = 1 : par.n
                dNdt((i-1)*nk + k) = dNdt((i-1)*nk + k) + beta(j,l) * b(i,k,j,l) * S(j,k) * N((j-1)*nk + k) - S(i,k) * N((i-1)*nk + k);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

where you need to provide the parameter $n$ and the implementations of the functions $\beta, b$ and $S$.

---

To have it run in Matlab, type

```
[t,N] = ode45(@(t,N)rhs(t,N,par), [t0, te], N0);
```

where the first argument is an anonymous function allowing for passing over a third argument (the parameter struct `par`), $t_0$ is start time, $t_e$ is end time and $N_0$ are initial conditions. Note that $N_0$ needs to have $n \cdot n_k$ components.

---

Choosing $n = n_k = S = \beta = N_0 = 1$ and $b = 0.5$ yields the following result for $t \in [0, 1]$:

[image]

Choosing $n = n_k = 2$, $S = \beta = 1$, $N_0 = (.2, .3, .4, .5)^T$ and $b = 0.5$ returns

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help dear @max-herrmann, but although provide required parameters and functions, I'm getting an error like this:    Undefined function or variable "dNdt".

Error in rhs (line 7)

Comment: The name (or identifier) of the function is `rhs`, the return value is `dNdt`. Maybe you put it the other way around. Btw, I just added the mandatory independent variable `t`.

Comment: Why would you use for loops in matlab? At least last time i used it it was extremely slow.

Comment: For educational reasons. Easier to read. Apart from that, I didn't know `for` loops were `extremely slow'.. @candancelik: Corrected an index flaw.

Comment: Well, thank you! But, I can't run. Did you try this code with your arbitrary variables $t_{0}$ and $t_{e}$? @max-herrmann

Comment: @Candan: Fixed another index flaw and added integration results.

Comment: Thank you Max! You're great. I will try to solve with correct functions. And I also need matrix form of this system.  I found 'equationsToMatrix' code and trying it. @MaxHerrmann

Comment: Hello again, I'm still thinking over this problem. If I choose b and S as a function is there any problem? @MaxHerrmann  By the way, my original equation is here: https://i.imgsafe.org/0c2f39d6f7.png and these are other functions: https://i.imgsafe.org/0c3542e5f2.png

Comment: There's no problem in choosing `b` and `S` to be functions programmatically. In fact, the above given code uses functions, not variables. Computation-wise, it will take longer to evaluate the solution.